# Observe of array elements in Polymer not working for boolean bindings

Tags: typescript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the PolymerTS extension. Im trying to observe changes to an array using the wildcard notation:

```
@component("ha-tags")
class HaTags extends polymer.Base implements polymer.Element {
    @property({ type: Array, notify: true })
    public tags: Array<HaTag> = [];

    @observe("tags.*")
    tagsChanged(changeRecord) {
        alert(changeRecord);
    }

}

HaTags.register();
```

This works fine as long as i use the following to set values on elements of the array:

```
this.set("tags.0.selected", true)
```

But the tagsChanged function is not called, if i change the value through a binding:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[tags]]">
  <paper-icon-item role="menuitemcheckbox">
    <paper-checkbox item-icon checked="{{item.selected}}"></paper-checkbox>
    <div class="flex">[[item.plurName]]</div>
  </paper-icon-item>
</template>
```

Result: the value of selected changes fine, when i tick or untick the checkbox, but the tagsChanged is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer observers only work for properties that are declared in the polymer element as properties. It won't work for sub properties. ( Polymer 1.0 does not observe sub properties )

In your example you have a list of tags. You could observe any change to the "tags" array (add/remove items) because "tags" it's a property of your element. But you cannot "monitor" a change to a tag inner property. ( That would be possible with Object.Observe, but Polymer 1.0 does not use it for performance/compatibility issues).

For your specific example, if you need to do something whenever the user checks a tag, you can add an event handler attribute to the paper-checkbox. In the event handler you can use the template method **itemForElement** that returns the bound object (the tag in your case).

An simple example of how to use **itemForElement** can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/lofarabare/edit?html,output

Comment: It´s possible to appear an little example using itemForElement?

Comment: @Muka . You can check this jsbin for a basic example of using itemForElement : http://jsbin.com/lofarabare/edit?html,output

Comment: Using the itemForElement method as described solved my problem, thanks! It just seems like kind of a workaround, but i guess its the best practice in polymer right now.